# login as other user without exiting my i3wm session

Tags: i3

I am running an Ubuntu 12.04 system. While I am logged in using the i3 window manager how is it possible to login as another user (perhaps using a different window manager) without losing my i3wm session?

This is something I can easily do when I am using Unity (and then use `Ctrl+F7` and `Ctrl+F8` to switch between the two users) but I haven't figured a way to do this from i3wm.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can ask your display manager to handle this, for instance:

- lxdm: `lxdm -c USER_SWITCH`
- lightdm: `dm-tool switch-to-greeter`
- gdm: `gdmflexiserver`
- kdm: `kdmctl reserve`

<sup>via [edgardcastro on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/5cedk5/is_there_a_way_to_switch_user_with_i3_how_do_you/d9w03vd/)</sup>

So on Ubuntu 16.04 (that is i3 over LightDM), you could bind the following shortcut:

```
bindsym $mod+Shift+l exec dm-tool switch-to-greeter
```

Comment: The gdm version doesn't work with the versions that come with Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: See [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/483388/17409) for a workaround.

Comment: I'm on 16.04, `dm-tool switch-to-greeter` worked like a charm.

Answer (score 4):

This doesn't really have anything to do with your window manager.

From any window manager, you can switch to a different TTY with ctrl + alt + f{1-8}, login as a user, and start a new graphical session (e.g. with `startx`).

Comment: When I try to do that I get: `Fatal Server Error: Server is already active for display 0`

Comment: Try `startx -- :1`. This tells `startx` to open the new server on display `1` By default `startx` tries to start any new session on display `0`, which is already occupied by the original session. Hence the error message.

Comment: yes, doing that started what looked like another Unity session in `tty-8` but it wasn't functional (I couldn't see the dash, couldn't start a terminal window with Ctrl+Atl+T, etc.). It seems that the issue is more complicated: http://askubuntu.com/q/416825/89663 but I am upvoting the answer as it pointed to the right direction.